# Cómo mostrar la fecha en español

Tags: php, laravel

Muestro una fecha completa con Carbon de la siguiente manera `{{ Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('l, jS \\of F Y') }}` pero se muestra en inglés, cómo puedo cambiarla a español, el timezone está configurado con un páis latino.

Comment: Gracias, pensé que quizás había alguna manera, sustituyendo las letras u otra manera. Gracias nuevamente.

Comment: Gracias @porloscerros me funcionó tu respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En config/app.php
cambia
'locale' => 'en',
a
'locale' => 'es',

Si esto no te funciona, colocar antes de imprimir la fecha o en el head

```
<?php setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_ES.UTF-8'); ?>
```

O también antes de utilizar carbon, poner:

```
Carbon::setLocale('es');
```